# using php echo inside google chart function

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I have this working script to show chart values:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Time', 'Total MacID'],
  ['15',  450],
  ['16',  520],
  ['17',  130],
  ['18',  220],
  ['19',  350],
  ['20',  640],
  ['21',  125],
  ['22',  260],
  ['23',  423]
]);
```

I am trying to get values from php, like (this is showing blank chart):

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Time', 'Total MacID']<?php echo $tablerow; ?>
]);
```

Value of $tablerow is

> , ['0', 207], ['1', 202], ['2', 210], ['3', 198], ['4', 219], ['5',
>   216], ['6', 203], ['7', 198], ['8', 245], ['9', 562], ['10', 674],
>   ['11', 823], ['12', 797], ['13', 485], ['14', 589], ['15', 693],
>   ['16', 751], ['17', 749], ['18', 388], ['19', 301], ['20', 281],
>   ['21', 286], ['22', 282], ['23', 257]

Comment: Use `json_encode` and `json_decode`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Time');
data.addColumn('number', 'Total MacID');
data.addRows('15', 450);
```

to data.addRows use php for condition and add element.

if you are getting data from .json file then you have to parse it. Something like below code

```
var newData=JSON.parse(jsonData);
```

Let me know if it is useful to you or not.